# LMR62421 Boost converter short circuit issues

Tags: boost, short-circuit

I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong... I'm trying to use LMR62421 boost converter ([schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr62421.pdf)) and I'm trying to boost Li-Po battery voltage levels to 9V. I just copied the schematic from example from datasheet and created the PCB, and getting short circuit problems when I connect my PSU. When PSU is not connected and I go through circuit with my DMM I cannot find a short...

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB]
[image: PCB Front side]
[image: PCB back side]

I've highlighted rather ugly looking connection in red circle just to clarify this ugly soldering job...

Comment: Do you have 10 uH and A of saturation current in that green thing? Also, what diode is that?

Comment: Are you sure that's an inductor and not a 10R resistor?

Comment: Even if it is an inductor, what's the current rating on it?

Comment: @winny It's marked as 10uH, but I don't have any more data on it. It's from one of those cheap eBay inductor bundles. What is your suspicion regarding inductor? Diode is 1N4148.

Comment: looks like only 160mA http://shop.rabtron.co.za/catalog/inductor-10uh-p-2430.html?osCsid=kb6ckh0bd1ic6rvq40brqemvo5

Comment: @Trevor do you think this diode burns immediately and then shorts the circuit?

Comment: INductor probably shorts then things fry quickly

Comment: pound to a penny it's the inductor won't handle the current. Once in saturation, it looks like a short circuit. Look at photos of SMPS converters, you never see that style of inductor used, I wonder if there's a reason?

Comment: "No more data on it" There is unfortunately not a forum-style sticky post here about not using conponents without datasheets but it's one of those generic advice which pops up in many of the questions and this is another example. But fear not, a simple search on digikey will find you tens of thousands of inductors to choose from, all with datasheets.

Comment: What does "short circuit problems"

Comment: Hi @Andyaka - I use over current protection on my PSU and it triggers it immediately. There is no load on the output, so the draw should be minimal (accounting for the capacitors filling up, ofc) but it still does not go beyond whatever I set as current limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you probably want a schottky diode rather than a standard diode. Sounds silly, but that can make a massive difference I have found. Secondly, with all these types of boost converters, PCB payout is absolutely key. You probably want your input and output capacitors much closer to the chip. You can also try sticking a load on it, as some of these require a minimum load to startup (on the first page of the datasheet it shows that the efficiency is poor under light loads).

The next thing to do is figure out how much current you are expected to pull from that thing and ensure your components can take it. If it is estimated to be a large current (this thing says it can do up to 2.1A) then you might want to make sure you have enough ground. You just have a small track, and most of these chips need a nice amount of ground plane to dissipate heat in order to work correctly.

How did you come up with 10uH as your inductor value by the way? Another thing about the inductor, the datasheet mentions that ferrite based inductors are preferred, due to perating frequency. Did you ensure to go along with that? And your capacitors, with these types of chips, you want capacitors with low ESR (equivalent series resistance).

I think this issue may be simply down to the PCB design aswell as component selection. It has happened to me before. Hope this helps.